# Java 8 streams - use reduce with alternative accumulator return type

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a piece of code that I use to generate PDF document, it's simplified just to demonstrate the problem.

```
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[]{ 100.0f });
    List<PdfPCell> cells = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> labels = Arrays.asList(
            Labels.ITEM_NAME,
            Labels.QUANTITY,
            Labels.PRICE
    );

    for (String label : labels) {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(label));
        cells.add(cell);
    }

    for (PdfPCell cell : cells) {
        table.addCell(cell);
    }
```

I want to convert it to functional style with Java 8 streams.

I know that I javascript I can use reduce like this:

```
let container = { items: [] };

[1, 2, 3]
        .reduce((container, item) => { 
            container.items.push(item); 
            return container; 
        }, container);

console.log(container); // { items: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

I am trying to use same approach in Java, so my code is something like this:

```
PdfPTable myTable = Stream.of(
            Labels.ITEM_NAME,
            Labels.QUANTITY,
            Labels.PRICE)
            .map(s -> new PdfPCell(new Phrase(s)))
            .reduce(new PdfPTable(new float[]{ 100.0f }), (table, cell) -> {
                table.addCell(cell);
                return table;
            });
```

But it's not compiling because in reduce function table is recognised as cell, types do not match properly.

What I am trying to use seems to be accumulator function, this is what my IDE shows me:
[image]

From documentation:

> java.util.stream.Stream public abstract T reduce(T identity,
>                            java.util.function.BinaryOperator accumulator) Performs a reduction on the elements of this stream,
>   using the provided identity value and an associative accumulation
>   function, and returns the reduced value. This is equivalent to:

```
T result = identity;
 for (T element : this stream)
     result = accumulator.apply(result, element)
 return result;
```

> but is not constrained to execute sequentially. The identity value
>   must be an identity for the accumulator function. This means that for
>   all t, accumulator.apply(identity, t) is equal to t. The accumulator
>   function must be an associative function.

All examples show primitive arithmetic operations like calculating sum and mention that these accumulator function must be stateless. I am not even sure if what I am trying to is a proper thing, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For mutable reduction you should use `collect`, not `reduce`:

```
PdfPTable myTable = 
    Stream.of(Labels.ITEM_NAME,Labels.QUANTITY,Labels.PRICE)
          .map(s -> new PdfPCell(new Phrase(s)))
          .collect(() -> new PdfPTable(new float[]{ 100.0f }), // supplier
                   (table, cell) -> table.addCell(cell), // accumulator
                   (table1,table2) -> table1.addAllCells(table2.getCells())); // combiner
```

For the combiner, I made some assumptions on methods which may or may not exist in your `PdfPTable` class, but that's the general idea.

Comment: It turns that what in JS is actually reduce, in Java is collect.. because it saves state between operations, right?